# localhost ubuntu xampp "There was an SQL error: No database selected"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I am beginner in work on xampp and I setup my localhost. I install Lampp on linux ubuntu 12.04 and copy the folder of my site in /opt/lampp/htdocs. this folder is exist on webserver and it works.now Xampp, PHPmyadmin, MySQL work truly on my pc and I can see my tables and database in phpmyadmin, every thing on my local host is true except when I want to load index.php of website I see below database error :

```
A database error occurred while performing the requested procedure. Please review the database error below for more information.
/opt/lampp/htdocs/product/domains/product.behinyab.ir/libs/kohana/libraries/drivers/Database/Mysql.php [368]:
There was an SQL error: No database selected - SELECT `id`, `route` FROM `arag_static_pages` WHERE `appname` = 'arag'
```

I search this subject on google and read more things but I cant solve this problem yet.
anyone can solve it?

Comment: You might need to post a bit more of your code here

Comment: What is the code for the part of your app that connects to the database?

Comment: Hi Sajuna I just copy all of files and folder that exist on my webserver in my localserver. I test my localhost by this code: <html>
<head>
<title>First PHP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>';
mysql_connect('localhost','root','mypassword') or die ("Connect error");

$res = mysql_query("SHOW DATABASES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
    echo $row[0], '<br/>';
}

?>
</body>
</html> and I can see tables in my database in local phpmyadmin. but what code is essential for you?

Answer (score 1):

specify which database you are querying. YOu can either do that in the connection, or in the query, in the following manner:

```
SELECT database.table.`id`, database.table.`route` FROM database.`arag_static_pages` WHERE database.table.`appname` = 'arag'
```

would actually be sufficient to mention which database the table is coming from, so prefixing the table with the db name in the from